# Live USB doesnt recognize any bootable file on usb. Booting from usb gives disc error

Tags: boot, live-usb, usb-drive, windows-xp, iso

Windows is screwed up and I cannot register it on my computer (product on HD doesn't match product previously on motherboard). So I decided to just run Ubuntu instead. I put the Ubuntu .iso file I downloaded off this site on a USB and tried to boot it from there but is gave me a disc error and never showed Ubuntu as an option.

I must be doing something wrong. It probably isn't as simple as Im hoping

Answer (score 1):

check USB is bootable or not. if not then follows this [step](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) to make USB bootable .

Afterwards you can boot from the USB as if you booted from a CD and proceed to install Ubuntu on your hard disk.

more information visit [here](http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/install-ubuntu-12-04-from-usb/)